# "vote early vote often"..Wait...what votes?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, voting, winter-bash-2015

- Topic: Winterbash 2015:
- Hat: "vote early vote often"
- Description: "cast a total of 250 votes on any seven consecutive UTC days".

My question: Does delete votes counts? Or we're limited to only up/down votes?

- Clarification: [I'm **not** asking for the confusion related to the count of casted vote because of the *refunded* votes that we get after the voted q/a gets deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271030/244062).

Comment: Hmm...we also have **close votes**.

Comment: You know, the answer you link to... Directly under it, Pops says it's only for up/downvotes. Does that not already answer your question?

Comment: @Kendra I have seen, but was not clear whether the delete votes are _excluded_ or _included_. Moreover the focus of the post was on the count of the votes after the voted content gets deleted. So thought of seeking a clarification based on this particular angle. :)

Comment: What about that exactly is unclear? _"this hat is for standard upvotes and downvotes on questions and answers."_ Can you clarify what part of that statement is unclear as to whether any other kind of vote is (in|ex)cluded? (I'm not saying the two questions are duplicates- They aren't, technically. I'm just trying to clarify how Pops' answer isn't clear enough, so it can be _better_ clarified to actually answer your question if necessary.)